# AngularJS : How to access scope from ui-grid cell template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How does one access `$scope` from a ui-grid cell template? Here's my controller code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  // i want to reference this from a cell template.
  $scope.world = function() { return 'world'; };

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: [
      { id: "item1" },
      { id: "item2" }
    ],
    columnDefs: [
    {
      field: 'id',

      // world() is never called and is not displayed.
      cellTemplate: '<div>{{ "hello " + world() }}</div>'
    }]
  };
}]);
```

See it in action here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/WYXeQShHWKDYDs4MIZnP?p=preview

I would expect cell contents to show "hello world", but they just show "hello".

Answer (score 70, accepted):

According to http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope, the grid has its own isaloted scope, so you need to use `grid.appScope` to access your application scope. The solution is to change the cell template to:

```
  cellTemplate: '<div>{{ "hello " + grid.appScope.world() }}</div>'
```

Comment: from filterHeaderTemplate I had to use 'col.grid.appScope.<ctrl alias>.myFunction()'

Comment: What is <ctrl alias> exactly? In according to the example above?

Comment: I can't be sure but the comment with <ctrl alias> seem to make sense for those using the "Controller as" syntax. So, if you've set up your controller to be available as an alias (commonly: controller as vm), then you need to include the alias in your chain, eg: grid.appScope.vm.myMethod(). HTH

Comment: I tried this `ng-change="grid.appScope.checkValidaton($event,MODEL_COL_FIELD,true,true)`. The scope function gets called however the `arguments` are undefined. How can I pass the `$event` and `ng-model` along