# Using a function in cell template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angularjs with ui-grid. One column of the grid contains a timestamp that I would like to render as a properly formatted date.

Up to now, I tried like this but the function is never called.

```
  $scope.formatDate = function(date) {
    return '42';
  };

  $scope.columns = [
    {field: 'date', cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">formatDate({{row.entity.date}})</div>'},
    {field: 'title'},
    {field: 'quantity'},
    //[...]
  ];
```

Instead, the function call is considered as a string literal. As a result, the column always displays `formatDate(*timestamp*)`.

I only found a non-satisfying way of achieving it by defining a function on each single row when receiving them :

```
  $scope.columns = [
    {field: 'getFormattedDate()'},
    //[...]
  ];

  $http.post('/api/data/').success(function (data) {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data.elements;

    $scope.gridOptions.data.forEach(function(row) {
      row.getFormattedDate = function() {
        return '42';
      }
    })
  });
```

Any better suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)?

Comment: don't use `{{}}` on scope function variables

Comment: @Asok Yes, the date filter works fine. Sorry but the question is actually meant to be more general than "how to parse a date". I would like to be able to call a method for others columns which contains something else than dates.

Comment: @charlietfl I tried but the whole expression is considered as a String. Then the grid displays `formatDate(row.entity.date)` in every cells :D

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle is [this what you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28127498/1134705)?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/5hyurkc1/2/) is an example fiddle of what I think you are looking for, maybe?

Comment: @Asok Yes :) I did not know about `grid.appScope`. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to access controller scope level functions using `ui-grid` you can use `grid.appScope`, here is a quick example:

```
{
    name: 'date',
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.parseDate(row.entity.date)}}</div>'
}
```

Full Example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid'])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.parseDate = function (p) {
        // Just return the value you want to output
        return p;
    }

    $scope.parseName = function (p) {
        // Just return the value you want to output
        return p;
    }

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: [{
            name: "Foo",
            date: "2015-10-12"
        }, {
            name: "Bar",
            date: "2014-10-12"
        }],
        columnDefs: [{
            name: 'name',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.parseName(row.entity.name)}}</div>'
        }, {
            name: 'date',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.parseDate(row.entity.date)}}</div>'
        }]
    };
}]);
```

<kbd>[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jnthnjns/5hyurkc1/58/)</kbd>

Comment: This is working fine but when I am trying to return a an element its not working. How can we return an inline HTML? Here I am trying to Show custom button on Group header lavel by using cellTemplate.

Comment: @aswininayak If you want to use html in AngularJS you need to use `ngBindHtml` and `ngSanitize` but, my understanding is that `ngSanitize` does not allow HTML form elements, it strips them. [In this example you can see how the input elements are removed and the div is allowed](http://jsfiddle.net/jnthnjns/5hyurkc1/51/)

Comment: Fiddle dead link

Comment: @Phil3992 Assuming you mean the link in the answer, it is fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To use function output the whole function call, not the arguments , needs to be wrapped in expression braces

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{ formatDate(row.entity.date) }}</div>
```

Comment: The cells are rendered empty. A `console.log()` in `$scope.formatDate` shows that the function is not called. But I cannot see any errors in the console.

Comment: create a directive , scope inside grid won't be your controller scope

Comment: You need {{ grid.appScope.formatDate(row.entity.date) }}

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the `cellTemplate` will not do anything if you don't include HTML in the format:

**will not hit the formatting method "formatRating()":**

```
            columnDefs: [
            {
                name: 'starRating', headerCellClass: 'blue', headerTooltip: 'Star Rating',
                cellTemplate: '{{grid.appScope.formatRating(row.entity.starRating)}}'
            },
```

**Works with the addition of a `<span>` in the cellTemplate:**

```
            columnDefs: [
            {
                name: 'starRating', headerCellClass: 'blue', headerTooltip: 'Star Rating',
                cellTemplate: '<span>{{grid.appScope.formatRating(row.entity.starRating)}}</span>'
            },
```

my format method:

```
        $scope.formatRating = function (starRating) {
        switch (starRating) {
            case "ONE": return "1/5"; break;
            case "TWO": return "2/5"; break;
            case "THREE": return "3/5"; break;
            case "FOUR": return "4/5"; break;
            case "FIVE": return "5/5"; break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the controllerAs: 'vm' option on my controller, so I had to do the following to call functions in a cellTemplate.

Define the function on the vm scope like this:

`vm.$scope.getBitFlag = (flags, value) => (flags & value) ? "✅" : "⬜️";`

Then use it like this:

`cellTemplate: "<div>{{ grid.appScope.getBitFlag(row.entity.prefValue, 1) }}</div>"`